# Compare strings in PHP excluding Null or empty values

Tags: php, string-comparison, is-empty

I have a simple question about comparing strings in PHP.

I want to know if two strings (also applicable in any other type) are equal, but I want to exclude null or empty values of the comparison, so, I'm doing this:

```
if (!empty($var) && $var == $varToCompare) {
    //do stuff
}
```

It's working fine, but I'd like to know if there exists some operator or function to do this avoiding the `empty()` part.

**My Background**:
I'd like to know this in a generic way, but here is my background to clarify.
I have two or more variables and I need to compare them with variables in my Database, but if I have a `NULL` in my database and my var is also `NULL` (or  a empty string) I expect `false`. Even using the `===` operator if the two strings are `NULL` or something like `""` I receive `true`. See the example:

```
$myVars = $this->getArrayOfVars();
$var1 = $myDB->getVar1();// could be null or ""
$var2 = $myDB->getVar2();// could be null or ""
if ((!empty($var1) && $var1 == $myVars[1]) || (!empty($var2) && $var2 == $myVars[2])) {
    //do stuff
    // I just enter here when the strings are equal, but avoiding the null or empty values
}
```

I checked the docs, but didn't find anything. Someone knows a function that can do this?

Comment: Isn't `empty()` generic enough?

Comment: Keep in mind that both `empty(0)` and `empty('0')` are `true`.

Comment: What if in your `getArrayOfVars()` method if you have a `null` or `""` replace them by `" "` (space) whith that you will not need the first part of the test (`!empty($var)`) ?

Comment: @JayBlanchard. Yes, `empty()` is good to me, but I belive that the syntax using this is a little hard to read and a function as `strcmpIgnoringEmpty()` or something would be more readable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best practice would be to make your own function :

```
/** return false if any parameter is empty() or $var1 !== $var2 **/
function strictlyEqualAndNotNull($var1, $var2) {
    return (!empty($var1) && $var1 === $var2);
}
```

which gives :

```
$myVars = $this->getArrayOfVars();
$var1 = $myDB->getVar1();// could be null or ""
$var2 = $myDB->getVar2();// could be null or ""
if (strictlyEqualAndNotNull($var1, $myVars[1]) || 
    strictlyEqualAndNotNull($var2, $myVars[2])) {
    // do stuff
    // You will enter here when the strings are equal, but avoiding the null or empty values
}
```

Comment: I was looking for a built-in function for this, but apparently create my own is indeed the best option.

Comment: Yeah, it is too specific to be a built-in function (in PHP... it may exist on Java's StringUtils...)

Answer (score 2):

Try `is_null()` and `strcmp()`
ie,

```
if(strcmp($var,"")!=0 || is_null($var)){//strcmp returns 0 when strings are equal
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not using strict comparison? Like `$one === $two`? In case one of them will be string and the other not, it will not work. Link: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Comment: But it won't work as asked, i.e if `$one` is NULL and `$two` is NULL, the test must return false, whereas `$one === $two` will return true...

Comment: The question was about comparing strings, right? So strings are not `null` by default.

Comment: but it is explicitly said "I want to exclude null or empty values of the comparison"

Comment: @t1gor. I know that strings are not `NULL` by default, but I'm trying to avoid `NULL` and empty strings (`""`,`" "`,`"0"`, etc...). Thx anyway!

Answer (score -1):

just put @ sign in front of the string instated of empty()

```
if (@$var && $var == $varToCompare) {
        //do stuff
}



$myVars = $this->getArrayOfVars();
$var1 = $myDB->getVar1();// could be null or ""
$var2 = $myDB->getVar2();// could be null or ""
if ((@$var1 && $var1 == $myVars[1]) || (@$var2 && $var2 == $myVars[2])) {
    //do stuff
    // I just enter here when the strings are equal, but avoiding the null or empty values
}
```

Comment: Please avoid using `@`. It suppresses errors and makes you code less maintainable.